# Best approach for SQL Schema to Mongoose Models

Tags: sql, json, mongoose

What is the best approach when transferring SQL Schema to Mongoose Models for someone who has no experience with NoSQL best practices. 
When should I use SubDocuments and when Populate to reference other documents.
Are there any converters that will take large SQL Schema and convert it to Mongoose Models (Couldn't find anything like this).

I know this question is kinda subjective and broad, but any reference or lead would be appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not strictly related to Mongoose, which is only an ORM for MongoDB, but on the design of NoSQL databases in general, and how they relate to traditional SQL ones.

In general, it is better to use **Embedded** (denormalized, SubDocuments in Mongoose) data models when:

- we have some information that **needs to be retrieved all at the same time**, the classical example is the address (source MongoDB website):

  address: {

  ```
        street: "123 Fake Street",
        city: "Faketon",
        state: "MA",
        zip: "12345"
      }
  ```
- **you have 1-to-N relationships**, in which the N elements are always accessed in context with the 1 element.

So in general, when we don't need to access related entities by themselves, we embed them in a parent object, or another object in general which makes sense to relate to. This has some advantages, like fastest reads, less database operations and atomic updates. This kind of model is one of the trademark NoSQL features, schemaless design or flexible schema.

The other scenario is the **Referenced**(normalized, using the populate method in Mongoose) data model that is better suited when:

- we **don't want to duplicate dat**a by embedding, because doing so won't give us better performances or simply the **performance gain is not worth the added complexity**.
  For example: imagine embedding the same **Manufacturer** information in all the documents for a **Spare Parts** db, it will be better to have seprate manufacturer documents and putting references to them in the spare parts documents
- we need to represen N-to-N\nested\complex relationships.
- we have data in a hierarchical structure and we need to mantain it for some reason, so we care for the schema structure and we want to preserve it.
- In general referencing documents is worse for read performances, because following references requires more queries in general, when i find something i usually need successive queries to get the details, but it is a more flexible data model because i can update or access every part of a document in the same way.
- On the other hand if more data is embedded we need less queries to get it, but updating only small part is more computationally complex, because it requires accessing the whole embedding.

A good primer on MongoDB design pattern can be found here and in the links that follow in the page.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/

Comment: This was extremely useful and has helped me wrap my brain around NoSQL Models, Thank you kind sir